# Database schema for storing ints

Tags: mysql, sql, database, schema

I'm really new to databases so please bear with me.

I have a website where people can go to request tickets to an upcoming concert.  Users can request tickets for either New York or Dallas.  Similarly, for each of those locales, they can request either a VIP ticket or a regular ticket.

I need a database to keep track of how many people have requested each type of ticket (`VIP and NY` or `VIP and Dallas` or `Regular and NY` or `Regular and Dallas`).  This way, I won't run out of tickets.

What schema should I use for this database?  Should I have one row and then 4 columns (VIP&NY, VIP&Dallas, Regular&NY and Regular&Dallas)?  The problem with this is it doesn't seem very flexible, thus I'm not sure if it's good design.

Comment: Is this entire database for only one concert, or will it be kept to store data for future concerts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have one column containing a quantity, a column that specifies the type (VIP), and another that specifies the city.

Comment: Maybe also a column for which concert is involved?

Comment: Wouldn't I then need two columns? One for description (NY&VIP for instance) and then another for quantity?

Comment: As Brilliand said: Why not have a column for the city?

Comment: That's not what I said.  I think we're up to four columns now (concert, city, VIP/Regular, count).

Comment: One column for city, one column for ticket type and then one column for quantity?

Comment: To avoid getting too complicated, though, a two-column table with description and quantity should be just fine for now, and easy enough to replace with something more robust in the future.

Answer (score 2):

To make it flexible you would do:

```
Table: 
    location
Columns:
    location_id  integer
    description  varchar

Table
    type
Columns:
    type_id      integer
    description  varchar

table 
    purchases
columns:
    purchase_id integer
    type_id     integer
    location_id integer
```

This way you can add more cities, more types and you allways insert them in purchases.

When you want to know how many you sold you count them

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is have one table with cities and one table with ticket types.
Then you create a weak association with [city, ticket type, number of tickets].

That table will have 2 foreign keys, therefore "weak".

But this enables you to add or remove cities etc. And you can add a table for concerts as well  and your weak table you will have another foreign key "concert".

I think this is the most correct way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE `tickets` (
   `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `locale` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
   `ticket_type` varchar(45) NOT NULL
}
```

This is a simple representation of your table. Ideally you would have separate tables for locale and type. And your table would look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `tickets` (
   `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `locale_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `ticket_type_id` int(11) NOT NULL
}
```

Comment: You're expecting him to store individual customers, I suppose?  This schema only makes sense if `uid` is a foreign key to somewhere.

Comment: Right. I did assume his users were apart of his application and actually had a dedicated table. You bring up a good point.

Comment: Well, without the user IDs, this table is essentially storing duplicate data (the auto_increment column doesn't count, since it carries no meaning).

Comment: @Brilliand Yeah. I really expect him to store some kind of user information. If he doesn't require sign up to request tickets he should collect some extra user information. I would at least collect names. Perhaps collecting IPs would be a nice touch too...